# how to fetch all data of query but show only limited

Tags: php

```
<?php

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products order by p_upload_date desc  ");
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $p_id = $row['p_id'];
    $p_name = $row['p_name'];
    $p_cat_name = $row['p_cat_name'];
    $p_url = $row['p_detail'];
    $p_file = $row['p_image'];
    $p_image = $row['p_image'];
    echo "
            <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-$p_cat_name'>
            <div class=' shadow portfolio-img'><a href='portfolio-details.php?product_id=$p_id'><img src='products/$p_image' class='img-fluid' alt=''></a></div>
            <div class='portfolio-info'>
              <h4>$p_name</h4>
              <a href='products/$p_image' data-gallery='portfolioGallery' class='portfolio-lightbox preview-link' title='$p_name'><i class='bx bx-plus'></i></a>
              <a href='portfolio-details.php?product_id=$p_id' class='details-link' title='More Details'><i class='bx bx-link'></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>";
}

?>
```

i want to load all data of query but wanted to show limited so i can get filter

Comment: Use an `if` statement in the loop to only show the ones you want.

Comment: Why do you want to fetch everything if you don't want to show them all? Why not change the query to fetch what you want?

Comment: Why don't you use `extract` to assign values to variables? Anyway, you're assigning the same value (`$row['p_image']`) to two different variables.

Comment: there is a parent div which control Filter of category if i use if then i will load only specifice number of rows ,i want to all rows to load but not to show therefor  i can apply filter over all loaded rows.

Comment: Then you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: can u please explain i also tried js but can't assign value of js variable to php variable